# PDO cannot connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, wamp

I'm having this problem where it says access denied, even though the login data is correct. I've tried multiple servers but it will keep saying access denied. The machine does have access to the server. I think it's my wamp that's not working.

[image]
[image]

Error:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xml'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Class:

```
class db
{

private $conn;

function __construct()
{

}

public function setupConnection()
{

    if (!isset($conn)) {
        $mysql_host = 'localhost';
        $mysql_username = 'xml';
        $mysql_password = '12345';
        $mysql_db = 'xml';

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $mysql_host . ";dbname=" . $mysql_db . "", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connectie is gefaald!: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $conn;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the MySQL host is correct? You will need to enter the ip adresse of the machine hosting the MySQL server.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I also tried 127.0.0.1.

Comment: check in wamp for pdo extension

Comment: @AhmedSunny - If the PDO extension wasn't available, the error would be different since it wouldn't even be able to create the PDO instance.

Comment: Are you sure for the user / password ?

Comment: _A heads up_: Your `setupConnection()` method will create a new instance on every call to it since you're using a local variable `$conn` instead of the class property: `$this->conn`.

Comment: @Dani Are you able to connect to the database from a MySQL client like HeidiSql (Windows) or Sequel Pro (Mac)

Comment: Check your db if the user `xml` is configured with those hosts.

Comment: The weird thing is, it works on my server. So it must be my wamp causing the problems.

Comment: @Dani I really sounds like a issue with the database user. Do you have any another PHP project setup on your wamp? I recommend you testing the database user from a MySQL client.

Comment: Your wording "The machine does have access to the server" implies the machine and the server are not the same, however you're accessing localhost which implies that the machine and the server are the same.

Comment: Is your database listening at the default mysql port (3306) or another ? In the later case, you'll have to mention it in your connection string...

Comment: I've tried adding ports, did not work. With machine I mean, I also tried to connect it to my webserver.

Comment: Added some images.

Comment: _I've tried multiple servers_ What do you mean by that?

Comment: It won't connect to any database. Localhost or online. What's wrong with my wamp?

Comment: This error normally means that you have entered the wrong password. As you can obviously get access to the database using `phpMyAdmin` try using the same userid and password in the script that you use to access `phpMyAdmin` if that works, then reset the password for the `xml` user account and change your script accordingly

Comment: Password and username are correct.

Comment: It must be that my wamp is somehow not connecting to the database

Comment: If phpMyAdmin connects to the database, then MySQL is running. WAMP does not connect to anything, your script is attempting to connect to MySQL. **It is connecting** because that error will only come back from MySQL if a connection was made. So either 1) password is wrong 2) username is wrong 3) that user does not have access to the `xml` database

Comment: Did you try changing the script to use the same userid/password that you use when running `phpMyAdmin`

Comment: Did you try using the `xml` user account and password to connect using `phpMyAdmin`

Comment: _The weird thing is, it works on my server_ By this do you mean that you backed up your server and restored it to your localhost? If thats what you did, User accounts are not part of a simple backup. You will have to recreate the User account `xml` in your localhost MySQL server